# Set color overlay on CCSprite - Spritebuilder/Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am trying to set a colour overlay on a few CCSprites by code as is done using Spritebuilder - It puts a colour overlay over the image. However all I can find to do so is

```
sprite.color = CCRed;
```

When I do so I get the following error:

```
Assigning to 'CCColor' *from incompatible type 'const ccColor3B' aka ('const struct _ccColor3b')
```

How can I set the color overlay on the CCSprite?

Comment: What do you mean by "color overlay"? Are you looking to add a colored rectangle over a given area (use CCColorNode) or are you wanting to colorize (tint) only the sprite's actual pixels and not the transparent areas? In that case follow Yves answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to assign a constant struct to an object. Instead try :

```
    sprite.color = [CCColor colorWithCcColor3b:ccRED];
```

or

```
    sprite.color = [CCColor redColor];
```

that will get rid of the specific error. However, i'm not certain it will 'duplicate' the rendering achieved in SpriteBuillder. There are many way to tint a node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SpriteBuilder (or haven't yet) so i can't tell you how it achieves that. There is CCActionTintTo[api doc](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCActionTintTo.html%20API%20Entry) but if that fails you could do it a bunch of different ways including the new v3.2 shaders. The API docs for CCColor [here](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCColor.html#//api/name/redColor)  offer a bunch of ways to choose a color. red being + (CCColor *)redColor